# Moved page (new parent) loads properly using obsolete URI. Why?

Tags: permalinks

I hope someone can explain how WordPress knows to properly serve up a page that has been moved - even when using the "pre-move" URI. I would expect to get a "404". Instead, WordPress redirects to the page using the new URI.

BACKGROUND:

The original structure of the "Our Services" branch of the Web site in question looked like this (using post_name values and leading hyphens to indicate lineage):

```
our-services
- technical-writing
- graphic-design
- project-support
```

The client decided to make graphic-design and project-support children of technical writing. The resulting structure looks like this:

```
our-services
- technical-writing
- - graphic-design
- - project-support
```

What has me confused is this:

If you point your browser to this...

```
http://example.com/our-services/graphic-design/
```

or this...

```
http://example.com/our-services/project-support/
```

.. then the browser will redirect to this...

```
http://example.com/our-services/technical-writing/graphic-design/
```

and this...

```
http://example.com/our-services/technical-writing/project-support/
```

respectively.

I'm not complaining, mind you. But I don't understand how this is working and I want to.

Note: Trying to access those pages from the root...

```
http://example.com/graphic-design/
```

or ...

```
http://example.com/project-support/
```

**does** result in the expected '404/not found'.

The .htaccess file has the default WordPress directives and this above them:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress uses the [`redirect_guess_404_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/redirect_guess_404_permalink)  function as part of its [canonical api](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/canonical.php#L0) to produce these results:

> Will also attempt to find the correct link when a user enters a URL
>   that does not exist based on exact WordPress query. Will instead try
>   to parse the URL or query in an attempt to figure the correct page to
>   go to.

You can [disable](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16557) this functionality via a filter or by using a [suitable plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=disable%20canonical), or it can be over-ridden via the .htaccess file.